# How were army formations deployed in the First World War in trenches?

Tags: world-war-one

When WW1 started, a stalemate settled in, which resulted in extreme stress and PTSD for both sides of the war. The Allies countered this by rotating troops in and out of frontlines, support lines and reserve trenches.

What I want to know is how army formations (divisions, battalions, companies) but specifically battalions (this is for a bit of game development) rotated between these. For example, did companies from the same battalion rotate between trenches, or did battalions switch out with battalions?

So lets say we had 3 trench lines: front line, support, and reserve line.

Would the rotation be:

Option 1: 3rd Battalion occupies front line, 4th support and 5th reserve, and the switch so the 4th is in the front, 3rd is in reserve, and 5th support

OR

Option 2: 3rd battalion is responsible for one section of the front, while company A and B are in the front, C and D are in support, E and F are in reserve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This obviously changed from year to year, and from country to country.

- For much of recent history, many military formations were triangular. Three combat companies plus supports to a battalion, three combat battalions plus support to a brigade, three combat brigades plus support to a division. That was the case during much of the Cold War, for instance. The US briefly played with two battalions as part of the [Armored Brigade Combat Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_combat_team#Armored_brigade_combat_team).
  In a triangular battalion during non-trench warfare, two companies could be "up" on the frontline. On the offensive, both move forward, the first to make contact fixes the enemy, the other forward company flanks and attacks, the third company is far enough to the rear to exploit openings with fresh troops. Or so the theory goes. The US Cold War division had 9 combat battalions, plus one battalion-sized cavalry squadron.
- **During WWI, the US went for square divisions.** That means a [division of two brigades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_division) of two regiments each with three battalions each, for a total of 12 (infantry) battalions to the division. The idea was to have one regiment in each brigade in the trenches and the other regiment in the rear. The divisional artillery brigade had two 105mm regiments, one per infantry brigade, and one 155mm regiment.
- Later on the Germans came up with a doctrine where the forward trenches were **thinly held** by a few machine gun teams and riflemen, and the main defensive force used counterattacks to retake a lost position. That exploited the fact that attackers became disorganized and outran their artillery and logistical support.

That was the theory. It didn't always happen as planned.

Comment: For completeness, the Italians wanted to convert to tandem divisions in WWII, but hadn't really completed that conversion by the time they made a nice hash of both their North Africa and their Balkans campaigns. Turned out that it increased bureaucracy workload without improving combat effectiveness.

Comment: @DevSolar, cynics would say that the purpose was to increase the ratio of generals to riflemen.